# How to inline form a deeply nested model?

Tags: django, forms, model, inline

To give a simple overview.

I have a model that has a foreign key to another model in which that model has a foreign key and so forth.

How can I go about expanding out the form so it is in a single view?

Currently, when I use a CreateView it shows the foreign key field as a dropdown. I would like to replace the drop-down with an actual form that can be filled out.

I will give an example on the models:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address_0 = models.CharField("address", max_length=64)
    address_1 = models.CharField("address cont'd", max_length=64, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField("city", max_length=64, blank=True)
    state = USStateField() # this is selection field # django_localflavor_us.models
    zip_code = USZipCodeField() # django_localflavor_us.models

class ContactInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)

class Generator(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(ContactInfo, related_name='contact')
    mailing_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, null=True, blank=True, related_name='mailing_address')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I want the user to create a generator form.
The page I get is a bunch of drop-down fields and code being the only fillable field.

I want to be able to fill everything out when creating a new generator form.

### Problems

- How to get all the models' form injected into a `GeneratorForm`
- How would I go about validating the form and making sure they get saved properly with their models respectively.
- What is a good approach to handling an unknown amount of foreign keys? Maybe more foreign keys in the models.
- Inline forming the foreign key fields when there are multiple foreign keys as well

(pretty much just want to expand web out to all models and grab them to their most basic field so they can be editable at the root modelform)

#### Notes

I tried using inlineformsets but it got to the point where I wasn't sure what to do with `ContactInfo` requiring `Address`.

I am unsure if it would be a nest of inlineformset and I don't know how to set it up.